# What environment to draw frame/box compatible with floats

Tags: floats, framed

I want to draw a text-width frame/box around a paragraph of text, like this[image]

I used `framed` environment from `framed` package

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{framed}
\begin{document}
    \textbf{Problem} blah, blah, ...
    \begin{framed}
        \textbf{Answer} blah blah, ...

        blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah

        ...
    \end{framed}
\end{document}
```

But I cannot use `figure`, `algorithm` environments in this `framed` environment. Any solutions?

Comment: Did you try a simple `\begin{center}\includegraphics{foo}\\ \captionof{figure}{Foo caption}\end{center}`?

Comment: @Bernard's suggestion would require `\usepackage{caption}`. (And the ```\\``` is not necessary, I believe.)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. You're right, it's not necessary.

Comment: @Bernard Thanks, but how about subfigures and algorithms? I can only use `algorithmic` environment without `algorithm`.

Comment: There should be no problem for subfigures: you can use `\captionof{subfigure}{...}`. Also, you can load the `float` package and the [H]` placement option for figure/algorithm.

Comment: Is your question solved in the comments? Any updates?

Answer (score 1):

The float environments like `figure`, `table` others can't be placed inside other environments or boxes as they really *float* through the text and are placed when the TeX engine finds a good place to put them. They are not part of their surrounding code.

So if you want something framed and floating, you need to put the framing code/environment *into* the floating environment.

Simple example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for example text filler only
\begin{document}
\lipsum

\begin{figure}
    \textbf{Problem} blah, blah, ...
    \begin{framed}
        \textbf{Answer} blah blah, ...

        blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah

        ...
    \end{framed}
\end{figure}

\lipsum
\end{document}
```

---

However, if you want the content of a normally floating environment *on a specific spot* you should *not* use that environment, but a non-floating replacement which gives you the same features like caption etc. without the floating effect. If so, see e.g. the `nofloat` key of the `adjustbox` package.